# Haskell lists error

Tags: haskell

I have this:

```
varCheck :: Defs -> [Error]
nameChecking :: Defs -> Body -> [Error]

checkProgram :: Program -> [Error]
checkProgram (Program n d b)  = do
  dupE <- varCheck d
  undefE <- nameChecking d b
  return undefE ++ dupE
```

And when i Try to compile i get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Error]’ with actual type ‘Error’
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘dupE’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return undefE ++ dupE
```

I really dont underestand why it treats dupE as a single element.
Thanks!

Comment: But the error that is shown, is not in your code.

Comment: Post the full code leading to the error. Also, why do you use `do` notation for lists -- it's not wrong but quite uncommon. Finally, note that `return a ++ b` parses as `(return a) ++ (b)` which in your case is equivalent to `a : b`.

Comment: Williem: my bad, it's the correct error now.
chi: I just think it looks tidy, how would you style it? Thanks for the return thing, corrected that, still get the error though

Comment: Not using do solved the problem.... Not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have

```
v <- expr
```

in a `do` block, then `expr` must have type `m a` (for some monad `m` and type `a`) and `v` then has type `a`.

For example, in

```
str <- getLine
```

`getLine :: IO String` and `str :: String` (our monad `m` is played by `IO`, our `a` is played by `String`).

In your code you have

```
dupE <- varCheck d
```

We get `varCheck d :: [Error]`. `[Error]` is the same as `[] Error`, so `m = []` and `a = Error`; thus `dupE :: Error`.

If you just want to concatenate the lists returned from `varCheck` and `nameChecking`, there's no point in using `<-`, which is used specifically to "extract" a single element from a list (or loop over all elements, really). Instead you can do

```
checkProgram (Program n d b) = do
  let dupE = varCheck d
  let undefE = nameChecking d b
  undefE ++ dupE
```

But now you're not using `<-` at all, so why bother with a `do` block?

```
checkProgram (Program n d b) =
  let dupE   = varCheck d
      undefE = nameChecking d b
  in
  undefE ++ dupE
```

Or, if you prefer `where`:

```
checkProgram (Program n d b) = undefE ++ dupE
  where dupE   = varCheck d
        undefE = nameChecking d b
```